# Debug typescript in sub-directories

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

Debugging Typescript works fine with modules that exist in the same directory as the entry `.ts` file. But I get a "File not found" error if I set a breakpoint in a module that is one sub-directory down. The error modal gives me an option to create file, if I click it, I get a sub-directory within the sub-directory. I think this has something to do with the `cwd` or `args` values in the `launch.json` file, but I haven't been able to get this working.

```
src/server.ts
   /database/dbClient.ts (debugger cant find this module)
```

After clicking create file directory structure looks like this:

```
src/server.ts
   /database/dbClient.ts
   /database/database/dbClient.ts (empty)
```

The code works as expected, this is just related to *debugging* in VSCode.

Comment: This happened to me when I was generating the target JavaScript in a different location from the source TypeScript code. I had to play around with the `--sourceRoot <pathWhereTSfilesAre>` compiler option to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this in your launch.json:

```
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\subfoldername"
```